# SQL SERVER replication or mirroring configuration to achieve the following scenario?

Tags: sql-server, cluster-computing, mirror

Suppose I have
 a Master Server called MASTER

a "Slave" Server called A

a "Slave" Server called B

a "Slave" Server called C.. and so on.

Every Slave Server have several clients.

The environment should work as described below, taking Server A as example:

When a Change is Made in A, it replicates it's changes to the Master Server.
Then, the Master Server replicates the Changes across all Slaves.  (B,C,...).

IF Slave server A lose connection to the Master Server, Server A clients can still operate normally , for they are connecting to A .

When connection is back, the  A Slave Server should upload it changes to the Master Server, and download
Every change made by the other Slaves, through the Master server as well.

Any guidance on which configuration  should I use is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like [Merge Replication.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx)